# Unable to change platform of setup project in visual studio-15

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I could not find any platform option in setup project for deployment.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to set whether it is a 32-bit or 64-bit platform ?

Comment: 64-bit platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the platform as follows.

From the `Solution Explorer`, Select your `Setup` project press `F4` key. In the properties window that appear (Deployment Project Properties), scroll down and set `TargetPlatform` to `x64`.Build the project and the setup will be for `x64` platforms.

[image: Set Target Platform]

Comment: F4 does nothing in VS 2019, how to do this in that version ?